# How do you issue a GET request and print the results?

Tags: rust, reqwest

I'd like to to pass a https string with an api key to Rust and print out the results of the GET request.

```rust
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_json;
extern crate reqwest;

use reqwest::Error;
use std::future::Future;

#[derive(Debug)]
fn main() -> Result<(), Error> {
 
  //Testing out pretty print JSON
  let obj = json!({"data":{"updated_at":"2021-09-17T17:41:05.677631986Z","items":[{"signed_at":"2015-07-30T03:26:13Z","height":0}],"pagination":null},"error":false,"error_message":null,"error_code":null});
  
  //Pretty print the above JSON
  //This works
  println!("{}", serde_json::to_string_pretty(&obj).unwrap());

  //Issue API GET request
  //Colon at the end of my_private_key is to bypass the password
  let request_url = format!("https://api.xyz.com/v1/1/ -u my_private_key:");

  let response = reqwest::get(&request_url);

  println!("{:?}", response);

  Ok(())

}
```

I receive the following output from the compiler.

```
--> src/main.rs:19:22
 |
19 |     println!("{:?}", response);
 |                      ^^^^^^^^ `impl Future` cannot be formatted using `{:?}` because it doesn't implement `Debug`
 |
 = help: the trait `Debug` is not implemented for `impl Future`
 = note: required by `std::fmt::Debug::fmt`
 = note: this error originates in a macro (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

Comment: await the future

Comment: Or, if  you are only doing a few requests, better use `reqwest::blocking::get` to avoid dealing with `async` at all.

Comment: You want to use the [`blocking`](https://docs.rs/reqwest/0.11.4/reqwest/blocking/index.html) API (ie. replace `reqwest::get` with `reqwest::blocking::get`).

Comment: This works. Thank you. How would you pass in additional query string parameters to the reqwest, e.g., an API key?

Comment: @marrowgari you'd have to use RequestBuilder api https://docs.rs/reqwest/0.11.4/reqwest/struct.RequestBuilder.html#method.query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`reqwest::get()` is an *async function* and it returns a *future*. A future represents a task that will be completed in the future. If you're inside an async function, you can use `await` to continue once the future is done and get the result. Such as:

```rust
let response = reqwest::get("https://example.com").await;
```

`main` can't be async by default, but you can use the `tokio` crate and annotate main with `#[tokio::main]`.